# Dynamically render string as html component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I type a prop that accepts `ComponentType` or a `string`?

Suppose the following code.

```js
interface MyComponentProps {
    Component: React.ComponentType
}
const MyComponent: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps>> = ({Component}) => {
    return <Component>{children}</Component>
}
<MyComponent
    Component="span"
/>
```

Trying this in TS gives the following error.

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}> | undefined'.

How can I dynamically render a native html tag using JSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of react and javascript, your code is correct. The issue here is the types. The string `"span"` is not a `ComponentType`. The type you want for `Component` is `React.ElementType`. If you check out the definition of `ElementType` it includes all of the intrinsic jsx elements or a component type.

You can come to this conclusion by yourself by rendering a `<span></span>` and hovering over or clicking through to the `span` keyword. You'll see the type is `JSX.IntrinsicElements.span`. If you click through you can see that `IntrinsicElements` includes all the html elements. I did a search to see where that type was being used which led me to the `React.ElementType`

Updated code:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
    Component: React.ElementType
}
const MyComponent: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps>> = ({Component}) => {
    return <Component>{children}</Component>
}
<MyComponent
    Component="span"
/>
```

Side note: React.FC might not be the best approach anymore. Instead it seems to be preferable to just assign a type to the props directly:

```
const MyComponent = ({Component}: PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps>) => {
    return <Component>{children}</Component>
}
```

More on that here if you're interested: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Comment: Thanks a lot for outlining how to reach your conclusion. This is the answer I was hoping for. Very insightful read about React.FC. Much appreciated.